# Problemas con la inversión de columnas en bootstraps para mobile

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Hola estoy teniendo problemas con una galeria que me desaparece cuando invierto una columna en mobile y la paso por encima de del texto. adjunto un ejemplo subido. [el sitio es este -->](http://qkstudiodemo.com/building/v1/interna.html)

el codigo que uso en el html son dos div divididos en dos columnas una de 5 y una 7 y el codigo

El css es este:[css del carousel](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/assets/owl.carousel.css) [css-carousel](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/assets/owl.theme.default.css)

```
<div class="galeria">
    <div id="sync1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
            <h1><img src="images/terraza-01.jpg"></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1><img src="images/terraza-02.jpg"></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1><img src="images/terraza-03.jpg"></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1><img src="images/terraza-04.jpg"></h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
            <h1><img src="images/terraza-01.jpg"></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1><img src="images/terraza-02.jpg"></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1><img src="images/terraza-03.jpg"></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1><img src="images/terraza-04.jpg"></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(document).ready(function() {

  var sync1 = $("#sync1");
  var sync2 = $("#sync2");
  var slidesPerPage = 4; //globaly define number of elements per page
  var syncedSecondary = true;

  sync1.owlCarousel({
    items : 1,
    slideSpeed : 2000,
    nav: true,
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    loop: true,
    responsiveRefreshRate : 200,
    navText: [''],
  }).on('changed.owl.carousel', syncPosition);

  sync2
    .on('initialized.owl.carousel', function () {
      sync2.find(".owl-item").eq(0).addClass("current");
    })
    .owlCarousel({
    items : slidesPerPage,
    dots: true,
    nav: true,
    smartSpeed: 200,
    slideSpeed : 500,
    slideBy: slidesPerPage, //alternatively you can slide by 1, this way the active slide will stick to the first item in the second carousel
    responsiveRefreshRate : 100
  }).on('changed.owl.carousel', syncPosition2);

  function syncPosition(el) {
    //if you set loop to false, you have to restore this next line
    //var current = el.item.index;

    //if you disable loop you have to comment this block
    var count = el.item.count-1;
    var current = Math.round(el.item.index - (el.item.count/2) - .5);

    if(current < 0){
      current = count;
    }
    if(current > count){
      current = 0;
    }

    //end block

    sync2
      .find(".owl-item")
      .removeClass("current")
      .eq(current)
      .addClass("current");
    var onscreen = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').length - 1;
    var start = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').first().index();
    var end = sync2.find('.owl-item.active').last().index();

    if (current > end) {
      sync2.data('owl.carousel').to(current, 100, true);
    }
    if (current < start) {
      sync2.data('owl.carousel').to(current - onscreen, 100, true);
    }
  }

  function syncPosition2(el) {
    if(syncedSecondary) {
      var number = el.item.index;
      sync1.data('owl.carousel').to(number, 100, true);
    }
  }

  sync2.on("click", ".owl-item", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var number = $(this).index();
    sync1.data('owl.carousel').to(number, 300, true);
  });
});
```

de ultima si alguien tiene una galeria parecida y que pueda implementar.

Answer (score 0):

Estuve revisando tu sitio con el inspector de Google y creo que tu problema es que estas repitiendo los id `sync1` y `sync2` en el documento html tanto para la sección desktop como para la móvil, cambia esos id por class y me cuentas :)

Comment: Si sabes que estuve mirando con un amigo y estoy probando eso, que puede que los id al repetirse no se ejecuten. buena mirada camilo, gracias!

Comment: Claro, el código únicamente va a reconocer el primer id y el otro lo va a ignorar por lo cual no le va a aplicar el efecto carousel y como en tu caso el primer id esta en un contenedor que se esconde en la resolución de un móvil pues es como si no se viera algún cambio en el sitio. Espero haber sido claro, Saludos !